# Using regexp_substr in snowflake to extract digits

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to do this but it gives "NULL". Why?

```
select regexp_substr('07.31.19.csv','/[^0-9]+/');
```

I want to only keep the digits: "`073119`"
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the slashes for? Instead, just use `regexp_replace()` and remove all non-digits:

```
select regexp_replace('07.31.19.csv', '[^0-9]', '');
```

I am not familiar with a fiddle for Snowflake.  However, [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd0a469e9d3a446db5207fe278ea3340) is a fiddle that uses MySQL.